# Using html+js as frontend for simple dll

Tags: javascript, c++, dll

I have written a C++ function that reads data from a txt file does some calculations and then writes the results to another txt file.

I would like to make this available to my colleagues by giving it a simple frontend.

My idea was the following:

I compiled the C++ code with the function as a dll file. Now I want to create a simple web-based frontend. For this to work the dll function would need to be called by javascript. The dll file itself is located on a protected folder, that is accessible from all my colleagues PCs. The html file would also be stored in a commonly accessible folder (not on the internet).

I googled this and it seems to be very hard to do this, requiring some browser specific plugins/extensions.

I don't understand why this is. From my understanding all web browsers contain a Javascript Engine which interprets Javascript code at runtime. So all I would need is a javascript library that is able to load a dll which doesn't seem to exist?

I think am having some basic error / problem of understanding here... Is it even possible to do this? Hope you guys can help.

Comment: https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/162

Comment: Thanks! I think that covers it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, loading a DLL from JavaScript running in a browser is not possible. Browsers cannot access the local file system or execute native code like DLLs directly.

To achieve what you want, you could create a server-side component that wraps your DLL function and exposes it as a web service. You could then create a simple web page that sends data to the web service and displays the results.

Alternatively, you could explore using a technology like WebAssembly, which allows you to run native code (including C++) in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I understand your second suggestion. Instead of compiling the C++ code to dll I would compile it to WebAssembly which can then be executed if the browser supports WebAssembly. As for the first suggestion: I'm not sure I understand what server-side component and exposing as a web service means here. Where can I get started on these topics? Thanks!